# How to enable and disable tableview cell according to array count in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uitableview

I am new in iOS and I am facing problem regarding to enable and disable cell according to array count

My code is like this

```
countcellbtn.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)ComplareArray.count];
```

I am getting array count I need to disable cell according to array count.

> Exact Issue: I have taken Button On Button click I am saving data on
>   the core data and on popup I update it. So If I Directly click on
>   third row app get crash.

Thanks in Advance!
[image]

I am saving data on button click and updating on popup click like this
[image]

But When I directly click on 3 rd cell app get crash because it index value get change [image]

[image]

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        static NSString *STI=@"STI";
        AuditNextTableViewCell *cell = (AuditNextTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:STI];
        if (cell == nil)
        {
            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"AuditNextTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
            cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        }

        cell.audittitlelbl.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[idarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        cell.nameidlbl.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[CheckpointNameIDArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        cell.passlbl.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[Passarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        cell.faillbl.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[Failarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        cell.warninglbl.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[Warningarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        cell.nalbl.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[NAarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        cell.popuplbl.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[Popuparray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ]];
        // cell.remarklbl.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[PFWNAArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

        DataModel *model2 = [AuditTextBoxarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.lblAuditTextBox.text=model2.AuditTextBoxString;

        //cell.lblAuditTextBox.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[AuditTextBoxarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

        cell.AuditCountlbl.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld)", (long)indexPath.row +1];

        cell.CaptureImage.image = [imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    // tag add on buttons
    cell.passbtn.tag = indexPath.row;
    cell.failbtn.tag = indexPath.row;
    cell.wipbtn.tag = indexPath.row;
    cell.nabtn.tag = indexPath.row;
    cell.Photobtn.tag=indexPath.row;
    cell.btnRemove.tag=indexPath.row;

    //method add on buttons
    [cell.passbtn addTarget:self action:@selector(btnP:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.failbtn addTarget:self action:@selector(btnF:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.wipbtn addTarget:self action:@selector(btnW:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.nabtn addTarget:self action:@selector(btnNA:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.Photobtn addTarget:self action:@selector(btnphotoClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.btnRemove addTarget:self action:@selector(btnRemoveClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"AuditPost"];
    self.devices = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];

    ComplareArray=[devices valueForKey:@"checkpointid"];

    countcellbtn.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)ComplareArray.count];

    //cell.userInteractionEnabled = (ComplareArray.count % 2 == 0);



    if (![arrIndexPaths containsObject:indexPath])
    {
        [arrIndexPaths addObject:indexPath];
    }

    if (![PassarrIndexPaths containsObject:indexPath])
    {
        [PassarrIndexPaths addObject:indexPath];
    }


    //background color change on button
    DataModel *model = [arrData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if([model.strSelected isEqualToString:@"P"])
    {
        cell.passbtn.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }
    else if([model.strSelected isEqualToString:@"F"])
    {
        cell.failbtn.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    }
    else if([model.strSelected isEqualToString:@"W"])
    {
        cell.wipbtn.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    }
    else if([model.strSelected isEqualToString:@"NA"])
    {
        cell.nabtn.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    }
    else if ([model.strSelected isEqualToString:@"PA"])
    {
        cell.passbtn.backgroundColor=[UIColor greenColor];
    }
    else if ([model.strSelected isEqualToString:@"NAA"])
    {
        cell.nabtn.backgroundColor=[UIColor blueColor];
    }
    else
    {
        cell.passbtn.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        cell.failbtn.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        cell.wipbtn.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        cell.nabtn.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    }


    [cell.contentView.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor blackColor].CGColor];
    [cell.contentView.layer setBorderWidth:0.5f];

    return cell;
}

//buttons methods

-(void)btnP:(UIButton *)sender
{
    sender.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    DataModel *model = [arrData objectAtIndex:sender.tag];
    model.strSelected = @"P";

    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"AuditPost"];
    self.devices = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];

    AuditNextTableViewCell *cell = sender.superview.superview;

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [Audittable indexPathForCell:cell];
    CurrentIndexPath=indexPath.row;
    NSString *String3=cell.audittitlelbl.text;
    NSString *String =cell.actuallbl.text;
    String2=cell.nameidlbl.text;

    CGSize newSizeClient=CGSizeMake(200,200); // I am giving resolution 50*50 , you can change your need
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSizeClient);
    [cell.CaptureImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSizeClient.width, newSizeClient.height)];
    UIImage* newImageClient = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();


    NSData *imgData = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation((newImageClient), 0.5)];
    AuditImageString = [imgData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];

    CheckStringShow =@"6";
    NSLog(@"String =%@",String);
    NSUserDefaults *defaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:String forKey:@"ActualStringCustom"];
    [defaults setObject:String2 forKey:@"CheckPointNameID"];

    NSString *FailString=@"";
    NSString *WarningString=@"";
    HighString=@"";

    UIAlertView *testAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Enter High Risk Reason"
                                                        message:String3
                                                       delegate:self
                                              cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                              otherButtonTitles:@"Done", nil];
    textView1 = [UITextView new];
    lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, 0.0,90.0, 34.0)];


    [lbl setText:@"Enter Remark"];
    [lbl setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12]];
    [lbl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [lbl setTextColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
    textView1.delegate = self;

    [textView1 addSubview:lbl];

    [testAlert setValue: textView1 forKey:@"accessoryView"];

    [testAlert show];

    NSLog(@"Text View Data =%@",textView1.text);

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSError *error;

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"AuditPost" inManagedObjectContext:context]];

    //  NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    NSLog(@"Result =%@",results);

    int imageSize   = imgData.length;
    NSLog(@"size of image in KB: %d ", imageSize/1024);
    int OCS=imageSize/1024;

    NSLog(@"OCS Image Size =%d",OCS);

    if(OCS<2)
    {
        AuditImageString=@"";
    }

    ComplareArray=[devices valueForKey:@"checkpointid"];

    BOOL contains = [ComplareArray containsObject:String2];

    if(contains == NO)
    {
        if (self.device) {
            // Update existing device
            [device setValue:Audit forKey:@"auditnameId"];
            [device setValue:String forKey:@"checklistid"];
            [device setValue:String2 forKey:@"checkpointid"];
            [device setValue:FailString forKey:@"failreason"];
            [device setValue:WarningString forKey:@"warningreason"];
            [device setValue:HighString forKey:@"highregion"];
            [device setValue:AuditStartDate forKey:@"starttimedate"];
            [device setValue:userid forKey:@"userid"];
            [device setValue:AuditImageString forKey:@"auditimage"];

            NSError *error = nil;
            // Save the object to persistent store
            if (![context save:&error]) {
                NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
            }

        } else {
            // Create a new device
            NSManagedObject *newDevice = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"AuditPost" inManagedObjectContext:context];
            [newDevice setValue:Audit forKey:@"auditnameId"];
            [newDevice setValue:String forKey:@"checklistid"];
            [newDevice setValue:String2 forKey:@"checkpointid"];
            [newDevice setValue:FailString forKey:@"failreason"];
            [newDevice setValue:WarningString forKey:@"warningreason"];
            [newDevice setValue:HighString forKey:@"highregion"];
            [newDevice setValue:AuditStartDate forKey:@"starttimedate"];
            [newDevice setValue:userid forKey:@"userid"];
            [newDevice setValue:AuditImageString forKey:@"auditimage"];

            NSError *error = nil;
            // Save the object to persistent store
            if (![context save:&error]) {
                NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        NSError *error = nil;
        // Save the object to persistent store
        if (![context save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
        }

        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

        NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        [request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"AuditPost" inManagedObjectContext:context]];

        NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
        NSManagedObject* favoritsGrabbed = [results objectAtIndex:CurrentIndexPath];
        [favoritsGrabbed setValue:String forKey:@"checklistid"];
        [favoritsGrabbed setValue:FailString forKey:@"failreason"];
        [favoritsGrabbed setValue:WarningString forKey:@"warningreason"];
        [favoritsGrabbed setValue:HighString forKey:@"highregion"];
        // Save the object to persistent store
        if (![context save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
        }
    }

    //example reload table
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [Audittable reloadData];
    });  
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
 NSString *CheckString;
           NSUserDefaults *defaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
           CheckString=[defaults objectForKey:@"CheckStringCommentAudit"];
           NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
           NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"AuditPost"];
           self.devices = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];

           NSLog(@"String 2=%@",String2);
           NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
           compareCommentArray=[devices valueForKey:@"checkpointid"];
           BOOL contains = [compareCommentArray containsObject:String2];
           if(contains == YES)
           {
               if([CheckStringShow isEqualToString:@"4"])
               {
                   NSLog(@"Text Value =%@",textView1.text);
                   NSString *String=textView1.text;
                   DataModel *model = [AuditTextBoxarray objectAtIndex:CurrentIndexPath];
                   model.AuditTextBoxString = String;

                   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                       [Audittable reloadData];
                   });
                   NSError *error = nil;
                   // Save the object to persistent store
                   if (![context save:&error]) {
                       NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
                   }
                   ///
                   NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

                   NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
                   [request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"AuditPost" inManagedObjectContext:context]];
                   //  NSError *error = nil;
                   NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
                   NSManagedObject* favoritsGrabbed = [results objectAtIndex:CurrentIndexPath];
                   [favoritsGrabbed setValue:String forKey:@"failreason"];
                   // Save the object to persistent store
                   if (![context save:&error]) {
                        NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
                   }
                }
                else if ([CheckStringShow isEqualToString:@"5"])
                {
                    NSLog(@"Text Value =%@",textView1.text);
                    NSString *String=textView1.text;
                    DataModel *model = [AuditTextBoxarray objectAtIndex:CurrentIndexPath];
                    model.AuditTextBoxString = String;

                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                        [Audittable reloadData];
                    });
                    NSError *error = nil;
                    // Save the object to persistent store
                    if (![context save:&error]) {
                        NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
                    }
                    ///
                    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
                    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
                    [request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"AuditPost" inManagedObjectContext:context]];
                    //  NSError *error = nil;
                        NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
                    NSManagedObject* favoritsGrabbed = [results objectAtIndex:CurrentIndexPath];
                        [favoritsGrabbed setValue:String forKey:@"warningreason"];
                    // Save the object to persistent store
                    if (![context save:&error]) {
                        NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
                    }
                }
               else if ([CheckStringShow isEqualToString:@"6"])
               {
                   NSLog(@"Text Value =%@",textView1.text);
                   NSString *String=textView1.text;
                   DataModel *model = [AuditTextBoxarray objectAtIndex:CurrentIndexPath];
                   model.AuditTextBoxString = String;

                   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                       [Audittable reloadData];
                   });
                   NSError *error = nil;
                   // Save the object to persistent store
                   if (![context save:&error]) {
                       NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
                   }
                   ///
                   NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
                   NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
                   [request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"AuditPost" inManagedObjectContext:context]];
                   //  NSError *error = nil;
                   NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
                   NSManagedObject* favoritsGrabbed = [results objectAtIndex:CurrentIndexPath];
                   [favoritsGrabbed setValue:String forKey:@"highregion"];
                   // Save the object to persistent store
                   if (![context save:&error]) {
                       NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
                   }

               }
           }
}
```

Comment: @Krunal Yes I mean user Interaction. According to Array count.

Comment: @Muju, There's no need to do anything for other remain cell, in which there's no data because when you click on that cell didSelectRowAtIndexPath will not call. JUST TRY TO RETURN 5 ROWS AND TRY TO CLICK ON OTHER ROWS & CHECK.

Comment: @Kuldeep No I have taken Button On Button click I am saving data on the core data and on popup I update it. So If I Directly click on third row app get crash.

Comment: @Krunal Yes but it not get solve.Please help

Comment: @Krunal Error Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[_PFArray objectAtIndex:]: index (2) beyond bounds (2)'

Comment: put this statement in first line of your button action and check: if (ComplareArray == nil || ComplareArray.count == 0) { return; }

Comment: @Krunal Yes Not solved.